# How can I change existing values of array of object from user input

Tags: java

I put my existing values to an array of object now I want to change my existing values of array of object from user input .How can i Change Some those values from user input .

```
              public class new AutoM{
                    //These are the existing Values

                            Name = "BMW X3";
                            Brand ="BMW";
                            Start = "On ";
                            Colour="Grey";
                            Fuel =5;
                            Km =11;
                            Oil=1.2;
                            water=2.5;

                            for(i=0;i<1;i++) {
                            BMW [i]=new Automobile(Name ,Brand,Colour,Start,Fuel,Km,Oil,water );
                            
                            BMW[i].show();
                            }

                     }
```

This is the constructore of super class

```
    public Automobile(String Name,String Brand, String Start,String Colour ,double Fuel,double Km 
    ,double Oil ,double water ) {
      }
```

These are the methods

```
 public String setName(String Name) {
 this.name =Name ;
 return name;
}

public String getName() {
return name ;
  }

public void show () {

System.out.println("===========================");
System.out.println(".....* "+ Name + "*......");
System.out.println( " " );
System.out.println("name  : "+ Name );
System.out.println("Brand : "+ Brand );
System.out.println("Colour: "+ Colour);
System.out.println("Start : "+ Start);
System.out.println("Fuel  : "+ Fuel );
System.out.println("Km    : "+ Km +"Kmh");
System.out.println("Oil   : "+ Oil +"L");
System.out.println("Water : "+ water +"L");
 
 
}
```

Comment: `public class new` isn't valid for anything.

Comment: "How can i Change Some those values from user input"  Use a REFERENCE to one of your `AutoM` instances, and call the desired `setXXX()` method?